# Popular CalendarView com dados do Firebase através de um DataSnapchot

Tags: java, android, firebase, calendar

Olá, estou com dificuldade em popular um CalendarView com um dados do Firebase...

é o seguinte:
Eu tenho um "CadastroActivity" onde eu cadastro eventos no Firebase com dias específicos, porém agora eu gostaria de pegar esses eventos e colocá-los em seus dias respectivos num CalendarView. Isso é possível de ser feito? Eu consegui, uma vez popular um spinner com o DataSnapshot, porém, não sei se é possível popular um CalendarView com o mesmo método. Abraço.